# How does a web browser select a font from a font family?

Tags: css, linux, firefox, browser, fonts

I recently tried to help a friend to fix an issue with fonts in web browser, when I noticed the following:

On a webpage (for example [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)), font style specification include the Arial font in the font-family list. By using the inspect element functionality of Firefox and deleting the `Arial` entry from `font-family`, the visual appearance changes.

The puzzling thing is, that I work on a GNU/Linux OS and I have **not** found any font from Arial font family (using `fc-list` and `locate` commands).

How can I determine which font gets to be used?

The question could also be: What font is "Arial" for firefox when there is no Arial-named font on the computer?

Comment: On Firefox, if you inspect an element's styles (in the Rules tab), look for the `font-family` declaration (if any). The font in use will be underlined. Additionally, Firefox has a Fonts tab as well, which will tell you the font that is used, as well as all the other fonts users on the page. This is determined by a font-family list, depending on what is available on your OS or what web fonts are loaded (with `@font-face`).

Comment: Sites that are coded properly have fonts and then font fallbacks. Browsers are smart enough these days to fallback to the _fallback_ fonts if the font specified is not available. If none of the desired / specified fonts are available. The browser will use the default font.

Comment: The Rules tab in element inspector is what I was looking at. Deleting Arial changes the appearance, deleting other fonts has no effect, yet I do not know where the Arial comes from. My guess would be that the browser would fallback to a different font, which is installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You provide guidance but you do not get to decide what the end user's browser uses since you can't be sure the font you want is loaded. Best practice is a comma-separated list where the browser will try from the beginning of the list and fallback to the next and so forth if the requested font is not available. A generic option like `sans-serif` is very common as a last resort for fallback.

From MDN:

> You should always include at least one generic family name in a
>   font-family list, since there's no guarantee that any given font is
>   available. This lets the browser select an acceptable fallback font
>   when necessary.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Comment: I think I understand the concept of fallback fonts, but where does the font come from to begin with? If I delete Arial (in element inspector), the site changes, however deleting any or all the other fonts does not do anything.

Comment: It would be a loaded system or User font on whatever device the browser is running.

Comment: is there a way to get the path from which firefox loads the font?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: As I mentioned, on friend's computer the "Arial" font is broken (i.e. accented letters are different and the font is definitely not Arial-looking), it would be nice to delete the font from the system or to change it for something else.

Comment: You wont be able to do that from frontend code at all. Certainly not with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Firefox includes Liberation Sans fonts into Arial font family and is happy to use those if `Arial` is specified in css. This makes sense since the fonts are designed to be similar.